# Show that collection of all solutions to $Ax = 0 $ is $R(I - A^+ A) $.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Show that collection of all solutions to $Ax = 0 $  is $R(I  - A^+ A) $.

I have been asked this question. Can anyone please tell me what $R , A^+$ refer to?

Answer (score 2):

It seems coherent that $A^+$ is [Moore-Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A$ inverse and $R(B)$ stands for the image of $B$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system) and [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse solution of a system of linear equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800677/moore-penrose-pseudoinverse-solution-of-a-system-of-linear-equations) for more details.

However, the best is to ask to the one who raised the question!